Any workaround to use remaining accounts if they are exceeding the transaction limit?
I am working on an Anchor program where I need to mutate four accounts linked to each client (two balance accounts and two withdrawal accounts). Here's an example of my test
const fundMovements = [
  { client: clientOne.publicKey, underlyingAmount: new anchor.BN(100), strikeAmount: new anchor.BN(-2000) },
  { client: clientTwo.publicKey, underlyingAmount: new anchor.BN(150), strikeAmount: new anchor.BN(2500) },
];

let backendId = new anchor.BN(Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER))

// Passing a maximum of 8 accounts (4 for each client)
let remainingAccounts = [
  { pubkey: clientOneWsolBalance, isWritable: true, isSigner: false },
  { pubkey: clientOneUsdcBalance, isWritable: true, isSigner: false },
  { pubkey: clientOneWsolWithdrawals, isWritable: true, isSigner: false },
  { pubkey: clientOneUsdcWithdrawals, isWritable: true, isSigner: false },
  { pubkey: clientTwoWsolBalance, isWritable: true, isSigner: false },
  { pubkey: clientTwoUsdcBalance, isWritable: true, isSigner: false },
  { pubkey: clientTwoWsolWithdrawals, isWritable: true, isSigner: false },
  { pubkey: clientTwoUsdcWithdrawals, isWritable: true, isSigner: false },
];

let updateFundMovementsTx = await program.methods.updateFundMovements(fundMovements, backendId).accountsPartial({
      caller: utilityAccount.publicKey,
      accessController: accessControllerAccount,
      role: roleAccountUtilityAccount,
      member: memberAccountUtilityAccount,
      tokenValidator: tokenValidatorAccount,
      ledger: usdcWSolLedger,
      whitelistedStrikeToken: whitelistedUsdcTokenAccount,
      whitelistedUnderlyingToken: whitelistedNativeTokenAccount,
      strikeToken: usdcMint,
      underlyingToken: nativeMint,
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    }).preInstructions([
      anchor.web3.ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ units: 1400000 }),
      anchor.web3.ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ microLamports: 1 })
    ]).remainingAccounts(remainingAccounts).signers([utilityAccount]).rpc().then(confirmTx).then(log);

Due to Solana's transaction size limits, I can't pass more than 8 remaining accounts, therefore I can only mutate data linked to 2 clients (aiming to do at least 15 clients per call (60 rem accounts)) because I will exceed the limit of 1232 bytes per transaction.
Question
Is there any way to manage additional accounts efficiently, so I can pass and mutate more account data without exceeding the transaction limit? Or is there any workaround in Anchor that can help to deal with multiple accounts beyond the standard limit?
P.S. I tried using LUTs (Address Lookup Table), but obviously they can only compress and store public keys and not account info or data.
Thanks in advance

Address lookup tables were designed exactly for this use-case. They allow you to declare more accounts in your transaction, up to 64 total. Definitely read up on them some more!
